# Need help extracting the value of a variable

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, logic

I want to extract the value of `v` from the following code into m2.

It is a little difficult to understand these chains. I am trying to understand the flow for a long, couldn't find any specific solution.

```hs
m1 <- newEmptyMVar                         
m2 <- newEmptyMVar
forkIO $ do
  g <- view (hasLens . to seed)
  let g' = mkStdGen $ fromMaybe (d' ^. defSeed) g
  execStateT (evalRandT runCampaign g') (Campaign ((,Open (-1)) <$> ts) c d') where
    step        = runUpdate (updateTest v Nothing) >> lift u  >> runCampaign
    runCampaign = use (hasLens . tests . to (fmap snd)) >>= update
    update c    = view hasLens >>= \(CampaignConf tl q sl _ _) ->
      if | any (\case Open  n   -> n < tl; _ -> False) c -> callseq v w q >> step
         | any (\case Large n _ -> n < sl; _ -> False) c -> step
         | otherwise                                     -> lift u
```

Helping functions

```hs
runUpdate :: (MonadState x m, Has Campaign x) => ((SolTest, TestState) -> m (SolTest, TestState)) -> m ()
runUpdate f = use (hasLens . tests) >>= mapM f >>= (hasLens . tests .=)
```

```
updateTest :: ( MonadCatch m, MonadRandom m, MonadReader x m, Has TestConf x, Has CampaignConf x)
           => VM -> Maybe (VM, [Tx]) -> (SolTest, TestState) -> m (SolTest, TestState)
```

I tried to include `putMVar m1 v` as the following in the `step` line

```
step = runUpdate (updateTest v Nothing) >> lift u >> putMVar m1 v  >> runCampaign
```

I thought these are just sequencing, putting `putMVar m1 v` in between produces following error.

```
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
    |
192 |       runCampaign = use (hasLens . tests . to (fmap snd)) >>= update
    |       ^
```

---

#### Some extra information

```
campaign u v w ts d = let d' = fromMaybe defaultDict d in fmap (fromMaybe mempty) (view (hasLens . to knownCoverage)) >>= \c -> do
  g <- view (hasLens . to seed)
  let g' = mkStdGen $ fromMaybe (d' ^. defSeed) g
  execStateT (evalRandT runCampaign g') (Campaign ((,Open (-1)) <$> ts) c d') where
    step        = runUpdate (updateTest v Nothing) >> lift u >> runCampaign
    runCampaign = use (hasLens . tests . to (fmap snd)) >>= update
    update c    = view hasLens >>= \(CampaignConf tl q sl _ _) ->
      if | any (\case Open  n   -> n < tl; _ -> False) c -> callseq v w q >> step
         | any (\case Large n _ -> n < sl; _ -> False) c -> step
         | otherwise                                     -> lift u
```

This is the code I'm trying to work on.

Here, I want to declare one variable `m1 <- newEmptyMVar` and `m2`.
Then I want to run the code from 2nd line(through the end) on two threads **concurrently** using `forkIO` .

*I want `v` to get stored in `m1` & `m2` from both the threads. So that I can manually check if both threads have the same `v`*

Hope it helps!

Comment: Is it possible that when you made your change, your editor silently changed some spaces into tabs or vice versa, or otherwise changed the indentation of the `step` line? Please include the exact code that causes the error.

Comment: I'm a little sure, that this didn't happen. As I did, tried to correct the indentation by reiterating over every line.

The exact code doesn't exist anymore, but I am adding a little more information here in the questions. Please see.

Comment: I do not get that error from this code, even after turning on the requisite extensions. To get good help, you will need to spend some time building an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DanielWagner, It should work the way I did right?

AFAIK, `>>` doesn't pass anything to the following statement, so, it must not matter if I put `putMVar m1 v` somewhere in between?

Comment: I don't know if it should work the way you did it, because you have not included nearly enough code to know that. However, your characterization, "`>>` doesn't pass anything to the following statement, so it must not matter if I put `putMVar m1 v` somewhere in between" is not accurate. For example, `[] >> []` is fine, but `[] >> putMVar m1 v >> []` is a type error.

Comment: Yes, that sounds correct.
I think I have included enough information here. I have a complete function here, and the dependent function.

And I just want to extract the value of `v` somewhere in between the function.

Please tell if you want some other information too!

Comment: I want some other information too, specifically, an MVCE.

Comment: Ok. I need some time for that. I will do it asap. Thanks.